# Installing Node 10 on Docker container - Keeps installing node v12

Tags: node.js, docker, apt-get

I had another question open for this issue but I realized the context wasn't correct since I'm running this on docker, hence this new post.

I am trying to install node 10 on a docker container, but the command doesn't seem to work correctly, or give the desired result. Instead it always installs node v12

This is the dockerfile

```
FROM php:7.3

# Install Composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y git zip unzip

# Install extra PHP Extension
RUN apt-get install -y libpq-dev zlib1g-dev libicu-dev g++ libxml2-dev libpng-dev libzip-dev
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_pgsql intl pcntl zip intl bcmath soap gd

# Setup SSH keys
RUN mkdir -p /root/.ssh
ADD ssh/id_rsa /root/.ssh/id_rsa.encoded
RUN base64 --decode /root/.ssh/id_rsa.encoded > /root/.ssh/id_rsa
RUN rm /root/.ssh/id_rsa.encoded
RUN chmod 700 /root/.ssh
RUN chmod 600 /root/.ssh/id_rsa
RUN echo "Host *" > /root/.ssh/config
RUN echo "  StrictHostKeyChecking no" >> /root/.ssh/config
RUN echo "  UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null" >> /root/.ssh/config

# Install Nodejs
RUN apt-get install -y gnupg
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | bash -
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs build-essential
RUN node -v
```

`node -v` returns `v12.22.12`

I've posted the entire file since I am not sure if something else is causing this.

I even tried adding

```
apt-get remove nodejs
```

in case the version was being cached, but that didn't help either.

Can't figure out why it doesn't install node10 despite all sources indicating that it should.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: If you need Node, can you build a separate image `FROM node:10` (maybe as part of a multi-stage build)?  Why does your otherwise `FROM php` application need Node, and why that specific version of it?

Comment: That is a very good question that took me way too long to ask myself. Especially because the container is to build frontend projects run on react. Not sure why it uses a php-7 base anyway, but I inherited these projects a while back, and not being very comfortable with docker I didn't want to change anything. 

But now having updated the container using https://gist.github.com/remarkablemark/aacf14c29b3f01d6900d13137b21db3a?permalink_comment_id=2736187#gistcomment-2736187 it all works now

Answer (score 0):

While this doesn't solve the original issue, I updated the container entirely, since it was only used to build frontend projects run on react. Not sure why it was using a php-7 base in the first place.

```
# set the base image to Debian
# https://hub.docker.com/_/debian/
FROM debian:latest

# replace shell with bash so we can source files
RUN rm /bin/sh && ln -s /bin/bash /bin/sh

# update the repository sources list
# and install dependencies
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y curl \
    && apt-get -y autoclean

# nvm environment variables
ENV NVM_DIR /usr/local/nvm
ENV NODE_VERSION 4.4.7

# install nvm
RUN mkdir /usr/local/nvm
ENV NVM_DIR /usr/local/nvm
ENV NODE_VERSION 10.24.1
ENV NVM_INSTALL_PATH $NVM_DIR/versions/node/v$NODE_VERSION
RUN rm /bin/sh && ln -s /bin/bash /bin/sh
RUN curl --silent -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.11/install.sh | bash
RUN source $NVM_DIR/nvm.sh \
   && nvm install $NODE_VERSION \
   && nvm alias default $NODE_VERSION \
   && nvm use default
ENV NODE_PATH $NVM_INSTALL_PATH/lib/node_modules
ENV PATH $NVM_INSTALL_PATH/bin:$PATH
RUN npm -v  # <= works
RUN node -v  # <= works

RUN npm install -g yarn \
  && yarn --version
  
#RUN source ~/.bashrc && nvm --version
#RUN nvm -v  # <= NOT works :(
```

This thread helped me out https://gist.github.com/remarkablemark/aacf14c29b3f01d6900d13137b21db3a